# Get all elements in a list or array using EL expressions in autocomplete combobox using jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, combobox, el

I want to get all the elements in a list or array dynamically using el expressions.

I am using the below code. If I use the variable istatus it's not working.

```
${claimNotificationForm.chattels[istatus].objectValue}
```

Below ones are working like..

```
${claimNotificationForm.chattels[0].objectValue}
${claimNotificationForm.chattels[1].objectValue}
```

How can I use the variable here so that based on the istatus value, the el expression should be evaluated.

THe below is the jsp code where I am using this.

```
 _createAutocomplete: function() {

              var x = this.element[0].id;     //value is combobox-0
              var status = x.substr(x.length - 1);  // value is 0 which is in string
              var istatus = parseInt(status);  // converted to int


              this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .attr( "title", '<fmt:message key="page.claim.personalclaimnotification.injury.select_info" />' )
                .val("${claimNotificationForm.chattels[0].objectValue}")    //works fine with 0,1,2... I have to use 'istatus'  here
                .css({
                    color: function( index, value ) {
                        if (this.value == '<fmt:message key="page.claim.search.object.name" />') {
                            return "#777";
                        }
                    },
                    fontStyle: function( index, value ) {
                        if (this.value == '<fmt:message key="page.claim.search.object.name" />') {
                            return "italic";
                        }
                    },
                    width: "286px"
                })
                .attr("maxlength", 256)
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                .autocomplete({
                  delay: 0,
                  minLength: 3,
                  source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                })
```

Comment: I see. Can you try to print istatus value and check what is it? Either using console.log(istatus); or alert(istatus); I think we will find the problem that way

Comment: Or you could perhaps ask another question about "Square Brackets in JSTL core Library/EL Expression not working inside jquery code". something like that

Comment: Yes. Will do that. @Faraz

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use [] at all. Just run a foreach and place a if/else statement.

```
<c:forEach items="${ListName}" var="emp" varStatus="myIndex">
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${myIndex.index==1}">
  //do something
  </c:when>

</c:forEach>
```

edit:

After learning more about the requirements, I went ahead and tested this by myself. Mine is working absolutely fine in both cases. So either the problem is that istatus is evaluating to some index which is more than the size of the list, or I don't know. Can you check what value istatus evluates to if you run `<c:out value="${istatus}" />`

When I set a random value to variable istatus, and if that value is within the size of a list, it prints out stuff, and if it is bigger than the size of a list, it prints out blanks. Meaning it just doesn't outright throw an error.

```
 <c:set var="istatus" value="${1}" />
 ...
 <c:out value="${claimNotificationForm.chattels[istatus].objectValue}" /> //it prints something meaning it is working
```

Comment: How can I use with out using the loop because I have a requirement to get a element from array/collection  from whatever index.

Here the index is present in istatus variable.
${claimNotificationForm.chattels[istatus].objectValue}

@faraz

Comment: @Ramhakrishna okay I am looking into it

Comment: @Ramhakrishna can you try to <c:out value="${istatus}" /> somewhere to check what value it is showing?

Comment: @Ramhakrishna Can you show us the full jsp code? and where that istatus is coming from? thanks

Comment: I see where it came from. But i don't know how to help further as my pool of knowledge has gone dry.